# Lightweight Objective-C XMPP Server

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xmpp

How would I go about building an Objective-C server? Atleast a wrapper for an existing C server? I require the XMPP Sever to be independent: self-contained, and doesn't require extra libs/ mySQL/ etc. Where do I start?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the easy bits that you *can* do. Then, when you get stuck, seek help on (on StackOverflow) on the *specifics*.